Understanding local rings and the need for locally ringed spaces
The following is a bit informal and I apologize for being possibly imprecise. I have been trying to get a ”geometric” understanding for the notion of a local ring. More precisely I’m trying to understand that why do we need the definition of a locally ringed space if we already have ringed spaces $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$?
Sure its nice to have a unique maximal ideal, but does this tell me something geometrically? In the wikipedia page they try to motivate this by considering the sheaf of continuous functions on $\Bbb R$ and then the stalk at $0$, but they only argue that $C_0$ is a local ring and do not give any actual motivation.
Is it really so that this is just the definition that makes things work nicely or is there some actual motivation behind it?

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281492/ringed-space-but-not-locally-ringed-space In a nutshell, it's not terribly difficult to make up stupid examples of ringed-but-not-locally-ringed spaces on which the sheaf of rings tells you essentially nothing about the underlying space.

@Tabes: I don't think that's really a complete answer to the question. One way to make precise what the OP is asking is: suppose in every application of locally ringed spaces we simply substituted ringed spaces instead. What would go wrong?

To build on the answer linked in @TabesBridges' comment, once you concede that you should be able to evaluate a function at a point then each stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ automatically comes equipped with an ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$ of germs of functions vanishing at $x$. A typical argument that one wants to be able to make in any sort of geometric context looks as follows: suppose $f$ is a function that does not vanish at $x$, then there exists some open neighborhood $x \in U$ where $f|U$ is invertible. This forces $\mathcal{O}{X,x}$ to be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$.
